# How do I remove windows and doors on Roll20?

Tags: tools, roll20

Roll20 recently released the "windows" and "doors" features for plus/pro subscribers, so that is great, and they are fun, but how do I remove them? They look and move like tokens, but you can't right-click and delete them.

I currently pile them up in some corner of the map when I no longer need them for that page, strikingly unelegant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can delete them (and any other token etc. on the board) with the *delete* key. First, click on them once so they are selected (and highlighted), then simply press delete to remove the door. You're right, there currently does not seem to be a way to right-click on them and open the context menu, but keyboard shortcuts still work. They also need to be clicked on directly to be selected, you can not select multiple doors/windows at the same time like you can do with tokens.

This also seems to work from any layer, no matter which layer you actually placed the door/window on.